# Does the method of computing feature weights for linear kernel SVM also works for radial Kernel SVM?

Tags: r, svm, kernel-trick, linear

I searched for how to find feature weights and found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390173/svm-equations-from-e1071-r-package). It gives the following equation to get the weights:

```
w = t(model$coefs) %*% model$SV
```

The answer mentions that the method is for SVM with **linear** kernel. Can I use the same equation for **radial**? Why or Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot, because for the RBF kernel $\mathbf{w}$ can never be computed explicitly since it is infinite dimensional.

$\mathbf{w}$ is the separating hyperplane *in feature space*, which for the linear kernel happens to be input space. The only thing you can compute is an inner product between $\mathbf{w}$ and some test instance *in feature space* via the kernel trick.